# How to make cloned DOM element JSON serializable

Tags: javascript, json, dom, ipc, electron

I'm currently working with [GitHub's Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) framework, and I'm trying to send a cloned DOM element from a preloaded script in a `webview` through their [IPC messaging](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.8/api/web-view-tag/#event-ipc-message) system to my renderer process. Though, DOM elements are not able to be converted to JSON, and thus the received message is printing out an empty Object (*`Object {}`*). Here's my code:

**Preload.js**

```
var ipc = require("electron").ipcRenderer;

function getData(element, trait){
  if(trait === "id"){
    var elem = document.getElementById(element);
  }
  else{
    var elem = document.getElementsByClass(element);
  }
  var cloned = elem.cloneNode(true);
  ipc.sendToHost("retrieve", cloned);
  console.log("sent");
}

ipc.on("incoming", function(event, initData){
  getData(initData.selected, initData.trait);
});
```

**Renderer.js**

```
loader.addEventListener("ipc-message", function (e) {
  if (e.channel === "retrieve") {
    console.log(e.args[0]);   // I want this to print out the DOM object
  }
});     

loader.addEventListener("dom-ready", function() {
  console.log("loaded");    
  var x = marks.list[i];
  loader.send("incoming", x);    
  loader.openDevTools();
  i++;    
});
```

I can't just pick what I need out of the DOM, as I **need** everything inside the `initData.selected`'s element and it's attached CSS.

Is there a potential fix for this? And if not, then is there any way possible to send a DOM element between these two processes, possibly with another program or node.js module? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the IPC only takes string arguments, then you should send the HTML instead, which means, use

`ipc.sendToHost("retrieve", cloned.outerHTML);`

and then this

```
var html = e.args[0],
    dummy = document.createElement('div'),
    cloned;
dummy.innerHTML = html;
// this will give you the node that you sent with all the inline CSS
cloned = dummy.childNodes[0];

console.log(cloned );
```

**Note**: We can only pass inline styling, the CSS loaded at the document level cannot be serialized with html