# Stripping functions from a large nested object

Tags: javascript, json, performance

Is there a more efficient way to strip functions from a large object than the following:

```
var objWithoutFunctions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

I want to avoid the `stringify/parse` combo if possible as the object might have cyclic references. And I'm generally curious if there is a way that performs better.

Comment: have a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914968/cloning-whats-the-fastest-alternative-to-json-parsejson-stringifyx

Comment: The only alternative is to recursively iterate over the object and delete all properties / elements that are functions. You can profile the code to find out which one is faster.

Comment: @zoubida13 thanks, I'm less interested in the cloning part though.

Comment: @FelixKling thank you. TCO isn't implemented in any browser at the moment, right?

Comment: Afaik no. The implementation wouldn't have to be recursive though (I used that term more to illustrate the problem). You can also implement a stack based solution.